# 0's reciprocal (Theoretical)

Tags: calculus, infinity

Background: I am in 8th grade and I like to study around advanced mathematical subjects. However, I do not know enough to be sure in my conjectures. Therefore, I would like your help.

I have a question regarding 0. Namely, 0's reciprocal. Of course, it sounds ridiculous- For 0 to have a reciprocal, another number must be multiplied by 0 to equal 1. However, here is how a reciprocal looks: X/1 *1/x = x/x = 1

Let's say that x = 0

0/1 * 1/0 = 0/0 = 1?

Now here are a few problems. 1/0, or, any number divided by 0, is undefined. However, through previous research and conjectures, I have hypothesized that x/0 is infinity if x is not 0. Therefore, assuming I'm correct, 1/0 is infinity. However, let us continue. 0/1 = 0, and 0 * infinity = 0/0 which I said equals to 1. What I am suggesting is that 0 to the 0 power is 1, since to get to 0/0, you need 0^x * 0^-x, which is 0^x-x, or 0^x/0^x. Now, since 0 to any number which is not 0 is simply 0, we have 0/0. Now, if I would follow the limit concept, let me make this equation:

f(x) = 0/x

As you may guess, this is simply a horizontal line, the x axis. Therefore, if we use the limit concept, 0/0 is simply 0. But, if we say that 0/0 is 1, then 0 would have a reciprocal -> infinity.

0/1 * 1/0 = 0/0 = 1
or

0 * infinity = 0/0 = 1

Please review my theory and tell me if I am, at the very least, somewhat correct.

I know very little of Calculus, so please do not expect any grand mathematical knowledge from me.

EDIT : I suppose that I don't want an actual answer as to my original assumption that 0's reciprocal is infinity, but rather an answer as to whether my basis for this assumption is correct: Is 0/0 = 1 and is 1/0 = infinity?

I would like a review of my theory/process in the comments if you can provide it.

Thank you!

Gil Keidar

Comment: If we use the limit concept, then the function $0/x$ tells us that $0/0 = 0$. At the same time, using limit on the function $x/x$ tells us that $0/0 = 1$, while the function $-x/x$ tells us that $0/0 = -1$. You can keep going with this however you'd like (for instance $2x/x$, or $x/x^2$). The result is that $0/0$ is all numbers simultaneously, which is kind of problematic if you want to do any sort of calculations.

Comment: If you want to have things like $(ab)c = a(bc)$ (which holds for *normal numbers*) and $0\cdot \infty = 1$, then $2 = 2(0\cdot \infty) = (2\cdot 0)\cdot\infty = 0\cdot \infty = 1$

Comment: There is the concept of non-standard analysis, using the so-called hyperreal numbers, where you introduce infnities and their reciprocals. However, the reciprocals are never equal to $0$, they're just "infinitely close" to $0$ (in the sense that the Archimedean principle no longer holds).

Comment: $\frac{0}{0}$ it does meant that numerator dived denominator at the point $x=x_0 $ when we calculate limit at this point $x=x_0 $ , by using euclidien division or asymptotics approximation

Comment: you might want to contemplate that zero is on the boundary between positive and negative numbers, so at the very least you can't be sure whether zero's reciprocal is positive infinity or negative infinity.

Comment: @Arthur IST (Internal Set Theory) is a way around that; the Archimedean property still holds, because every theorem of ZFC is a theorem of IST (and vice versa, more-or-less), but you still get weird infinitesimals. (All apparent contradictions are basically due to the fact that not everything that you want to be a set is a set.) (To the OP: This doesn't really help answer your question.)

Comment: In calculus, $\dfrac00$ is called an _indeterminate form_. Sometimes, when calculating a limit, you get something like $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{2+x}{1+x}$, and you can just substitute in $0$ for $x$ to get $\dfrac21=2$ and that's the right answer. However, if you have $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{2^x-1}x$, and you substitute $x=0$ into it, you get $\dfrac00$, which tells you _nothing_ about what the limit evaluates to. $\dfrac00$ is called indeterminate, because a limit of the form $\dfrac00$ can evaluate to _anything_. (If you're curious, that last limit evaluates to the irrational number $0.693\dots$.)